# How to close xml file

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDataDocument();
xmlDocument.DataSet.ReadXml(@"E:\Projects\...\PlayerSubReport.rdlc");
```

I am reading xml file and set to a dataset.
My requirement is how to close xml from reading.

Comment: When asking a question, please provide in what language your code is written and ask the question as clear as possible.

Comment: thanks jens for edit

Answer (score 1):

To start with [XmlDataDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class is now obsolete. The alternative is to use XMLDocument, but even then you need to rely on garbage collector to close your xml file since `XmlDocument` class does not implement `IDisposable`. Something like this:

```
nodes = null;
xml = null;
GC.Collect();
```

An alternative is to read the the data of XML using the XMLReader since it uses less memory.

Comment: any other solution to close....its important for me because i want to add datatable to dataset....but it mapped in to current xml....

Comment: @sams:- As I answered, you can use the `XMLReader` to read your xml file as it takes less resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`DataTable.ReadXml(string fileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable.ReadXml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DataSet.ReadXml(string fileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to populate the DataTable/DataSet with your data, if your XML is in the same format as what your DataTable/DataSet is expecting.

Sample code as how you could call it:

```
TestingDataSet.TestingDTDataTable dt = new TestingDataSet.TestingDTDataTable();
dt.ReadXml(@"E:\Projects\...\PlayerSubReport.rdlc");
```

Comment: my objective is reorder the xml field..for that i changed my xml to dataset and link one of the datatable to grid and change the order of the field in grid and then change datagridview value in to datatable then remove the linked datatable and replace my new datatable with same name....while removing datatable which is showing the error ds mapped to xml i want to recover from situation ....this is my context....

Comment: Please update your question with the mentioned error. The ReadXml methods that I mentioned and that you are using both do not lock a file for writing after the reading is complete

Comment: my  one is locking.....i will try u r one , and check .....whether its locking or not...